# Using PIMPL to include std::future in c++ dll

Tags: c++11, future, pimpl-idiom

I'm trying to use std::future in a C++ dll that is wrapped by a CLR dll.

So In my header file in my C++ dll I have the following:

```
#include <future>

std::vector<std::future<bool>> m_futureVector;
```

But when I build I get the error:

**error C1189: #error :   is not supported when compiling with /clr or /clr:pure.**

So I have been trying to solve this by using the pimpl method described in this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9771f61c-05b7-4e3e-96fb-ac9ea31ac3f4/c11-concurrency-thread-atomic-and-ccli

I have done the following but I cannot get the assignment of the future correct:

Header file:

```
    struct intern;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<intern>> m_futureVector;
```

cpp file:

```
struct intern
{
    intern(std::future<bool> ini)
    {
        //i = ini;//error - 'cannot be referenced - it is a deleted function'
        i = std::async(ini); // error - no operator found which takes a rh operator of std::future
    }
    std::future<bool> i;
};
```

Can I use this technique to solve my problem??
And if so what is the proper way to assign the future in the struct?

Answer (score 1):

From [this documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/future/future/), it says that the
Copy constructor for a future is disabled.

I'll suggest you to take a rvalue reference and move it into the inner class.

```
struct intern
{
    intern(std::future<bool>&& ini)
    : _i(std::move(ini))
    {  }
    std::future<bool> i;
};
```

I haven't tried to compile it, but it should work.

Comment: Yes this builds thanks.  Before I was doing this to add to the vector: myFuture = std::async(do stuff); m_futureVector.push_back(myFuture);  How do I now push a future onto the vector with this new method??

Comment: OK I have tried the following and all give errors: std::unique_ptr<std::future<bool>> uniquePtr = std::make_unique<std::future<bool>>(myFuture );  - attempting to reference a deleted function

Comment: std::unique_ptr<intern> uniquePtr = std::make_unique<intern>(myFuture ); - cannot convert argument 1 from std::future>bool> to std::future<bool> &&

Comment: @harryboy A future is move only.  Stop trying to copy it.  If you do not know how to work with move only types, google it and learn.